# Minimization Optimization

Tags: optimization, computational-mathematics

MAPE (Mean Average Percentage Error):Let 
$\left\{p_{1},p_{2},p_{3},p_{4}\right\} $ be the numbers $1,-4,4,-5$
respectively. Find the number $x$ that minimizes the Mean Average
Percentage Error, 
\begin{equation*}
f\left( x\right) =\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^{4}\left\vert \frac{x-p_{i}}{p_{i}}
\right\vert
\end{equation*}
by minimizing the sum $\mu _{1}+\mu _{2}+\mu _{3}+\mu _{4}$ subject to 
\begin{equation*}
\left\vert \frac{x-p_{i}}{p_{i}}\right\vert \leq \mu _{i}\quad or\
equivalently\quad \left\vert x-p_{i}\right\vert \leq \left\vert
p_{i}\right\vert \mu _{i}
\end{equation*}
What is the dual program (and its solution) for this problem. Complementary
slackness has a natural intepretation for this problem. What is it?

SOLUTION :WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR

Minimize $z=\mu_{1}+\mu_{2}+\mu_{3}+\mu_{4}$ 
subject to
\begin{equation*}
\left\vert \frac{x-1}{1}\right\vert \leq \mu _{1}\quad ,\\
\left\vert \frac{x+4}{-4}\right\vert \leq \mu _{2}\quad ,\\
\left\vert \frac{x-4}{4}\right\vert \leq \mu _{3}\quad ,\\
\left\vert \frac{x+5}{-5}\right\vert \leq \mu _{4}\quad
\end{equation*}
Continuing in this way , we have the following constraints

$x-\mu_{1}\leq1$ , $x+\mu_{1}\geq1$

$x-4\mu_{2}\leq -4$ , $x+4\mu_{2}\geq -4$

$x-4\mu_{3}\leq 4$ , $x+4\mu_{3}\geq 4$

$x-5\mu_{4}\leq -5$ , $x+\mu_{4}\geq -5$

However, $x$ is free, so we replace it by $x=u-v$ to obtain

$u-v-\mu_{1}\leq1$ , $u-v+\mu_{1}\geq 1$

$-u+v+4\mu_{2}\geq 4$ , $-u+v-4\mu_{2}\leq 4$

$u-v-4\mu_{3}\leq 4$ , $u-v+4\mu_{3}\geq 4$

$-u+v+5\mu_{4}\geq 5$ , $-u+v-\mu_{4}\leq 5$

WHAT DO I DO NEXT, IS MY HEADACHE ???

Comment: How is $\mu_i$ defined ?

Comment: Hi you are missing some \$ signs for your formatting.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yourself?

Comment: I totally dont understand this problem.

Comment: $\mu = \displaystyle\frac{y_1+\cdots + y_n}{n}$.